# Vector field on a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a nonconstant smooth function. If $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ be a geodesic without any conjugate point on $M$ and it does not pass through any critical point of $f$, then is it possible that there exists a smooth vector field $W(t)$ on $\gamma(t)$ such that $df_{\gamma(t))}(W(t))>0$?
 Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. $f$ being nonconstant does not imply $f$ is non constant in a neighbourhood of $\gamma$. In that case the answer is clearly no.

Comment: (In additiion $\gamma$ could pass through a global minimum of $f$)

Comment: Yes I understand my mistake. I have edited the question

Comment: You can just take $W(t) = \nabla f(\gamma(t))$.